# Microsoft ASP.NET Core Antiforgery token not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am working on an ASP.NET Core application that uses IdentityServer4.  I am hosting the solution through docker with an nginx reverse proxy.  When I try to post to the Login page, I get an error on validation of the antiforgery token.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter
> Antiforgery token validation failed. The required antiforgery request
> token was not provided in either form field
> "__RequestVerificationToken" or header value
> "RequestVerificationToken".
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The
> required antiforgery request token was not provided in either form
> field "__RequestVerificationToken" or header value
> "RequestVerificationToken".    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext
> context)

I can see the form field value in the log, and the cookie in the header, so why can't they be validated?

Things I have tried:

- reinstalling .net5.0
- clearing cookies
- checking headers to be sure that nginx is passing the headers (cookie is passed, antiforgery is not, but I thought the form value would suffice)
- running the IdentityServer standalone from Visual Studio, same error

Log excerpts:

> Request Header: Cookie, VALUE: [".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9TtSrW0hzOs=CfDJ8GgewuQrCt5Jh-ZpCaVVYMMQsSzQ4szfdbzotf4mpAyz6PjMg6kJVx3NTZOvLmayoal1pJlCneuovMaik1U7pOvTRQ_m9lkCbOds-q7Zs9qI2YPFL4ilX7YkFaO5Et7qjZDg1e5hQsiLM2vgjDZhv0A"]

> Request https localhost/Account/Login
> ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3DCoords.bff%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%2520Coords.Api%2520offline_access%26code_challenge%3DfTSFoTHs6lrn9fseCUTGHdNhuo9xaAQdphEicw8xte8%26code_challenge_method%3DS256%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D637772105565376501.YzAxNDQ3ZjItZTA4Yi00ODNiLTgyOWYtNDkwMWY3MjNiMjkyMzAzZDcwNTktMWViMi00N2Y3LWI3MzktOTdlYmJjYTQ1OWY5%26state%3DCfDJ8B4VnExs86BAldFmBUrB8GW4Xk_0uT-IxLONJqQZ33WwaIueELfuiXCRLe-OBIw33-6xAnOZddCNv5Xx2SEEjWtkTKMRR4gmFU9v21Ise1xo5b8wdx4-bBT-JQP8LZHaxY_It-IaL8cPZB1-MnWiMpVXshtVgCLlXuYdOqiFhcK__C25t4kkuiWSzQChu1Dicp36S1Hs2Dd-mxMY41XvSZtnQOH5bZMosFD7nCjkAnHAbZSxH1B-JhAzszdn8mHrPi9EKQ8Qn2alFxjHYz8WfDny8McOdv32DkhXxT2LAmh1TNY-seQFZJpJkbFQpy3lOnnR0oXL_jDJnEYby5mHwYL52NoWSDBuUY3IpFeJe5GEK7u4PEpKBfN0Ayqbz1MxnRlUAzy_-PoQ5kDQOtO8i_2IuW4AcIz8I5X6WMz0Eejl%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NETSTANDARD2_0%26x-client-ver%3D5.5.0.0&Username=bob&Password=Pass123%24&button=login&**__RequestVerificationToken**=CfDJ8GgewuQrCt5Jh-ZpCaVVYMMkknIKLHytN5j4VPnY61AY756THCD_aees86xhdtngCe-WZNN_cJ-B6CC0pHvYuNmT2cbkIxCgE-msI_1PD_ME7V55ZOR9JwFQJ2nRBTWv3GZnMHdzgxYpCW52AS1MqW0&RememberLogin=false

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of the ASP.NET Core service/client?

Comment: No, just one instance of each service. Nginx proxy, nginx web server serving the SPA, net core api, net core bff, net core idsrv, sql server db

Comment: way late to this convo, but its prolly the Nginx proxy. Im way out of my element on this stuff but I'm using a windows 2019 web server behind a load balancer using azure single sign on... works perfect until its behind the load balancer which i believe is essentially a proxy of sorts. unfortunately i don't have a solution for the issue. I'm currently using forward headers which does allow the authentication process to work, now just to figure out the AntiForgery issue...